# how to change view of date picker and display like calender in datepicker in android?

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker, android-date

**

### Developing Daily Expense Application in Android

**
I have seen many android application where user can select Date from date picker.

In my application I have used date field in activity.

so I want to design my own datepicker like calender view.

I want to display datepicker like...

1) first image
[datepicker](https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/2a4a413d3f7df61adffdb5c098dada8efcffd92f/687474703a2f2f796573796f2e6769746875622e636f6d2f696d616765732f616e64726f69645f646174657069636b65722e706e67)

2) second image
[datepicker](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_O-vNZWmCFxA/TNw8rT3GeII/AAAAAAAAAAs/wPC6Y0LCeKk/s1600/full-2_3-2.png)

I am developing application like Daily expense...
So If anybody knows how to develop stylish datepicker in android.plz reply.

Comment: yes I have created.It is done.

Comment: yes i have used your link.

Comment: yes marked this answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in to this example

http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/

If you change the layout background you will get what you want

You copy the below code and in button onclick call

```
     Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SimpleCalendarViewActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
```

And in android Manifest File for SimpleCalendarViewActivity add this theme.. It will display this as a Dialog. check it out

```
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Comment: yes I have seen this but i want this view in dialog.so user can choose date from dialog and it will set in my activity date field.

Comment: please see following link https://lh4.ggpht.com/7pHx6dAFw-mkO2qWGwzalhQ7WW7rtZGFoiewnC19xW7r6Z4MUOiEE1H5RtiFddKCjc_I

Comment: I want this type of date field.in this image there is date field for user and user press on image button it will open dialog to select date.

Comment: how to create segment control like...https://lh4.ggpht.com/7pHx6dAFw-mkO2qWGwzalhQ7WW7rtZGFoiewnC19xW7r6Z4MUOiEE1H5RtiFddKCjc_I

Comment: @NileshPatel try this link http://ttlnews.blogspot.in/2011/09/segmented-button-control-in-android.html for segment control

Comment: what is pending transaction in Daily Expense Manager app in android?